# Problem with mirroring and animation rigging

Tags: animation, rigging, mirror

Welcome

I’m beginner in that and not the best in english so please for your understanding.

I have problem with mirroring some object on my work. It doesen’t mowing like I wanted to when i making animation. Problem probably is caused by object pivot (what is mirroring object for second one - Picture) point that don’t follow to rotation of bone. I think that I understandably explained my problem. I wanna to know how to solve that issue.

Link to download: https://download1523.mediafire.com/qu1p77h764rg/13xrbrf71bcl7il/LIGER.blend

May it be possible to understand words because I mostly used my country language in naming the objects etc.

Thank you in advance for your answer.[image]

Comment: please add your blend file to your post.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that **you have *several* armatures, each with *only 1* bone. But what you want is *only 1* armature with *several* bones.**

You can join the armatures with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. But you need to do some clean-up first. Most of your objects have a *Mirror* modifier. I would apply them and make a full rig with mirrored bones. If you want to keep the *Mirror* modifiers for some reason you need to move the *Armature* modifier below the *Mirror* modifier on the stack.

**Clean-up**

- select all object and rotate them by -90° around the Z-axis (<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, `-90`). This places the dragon correctly. The front is in the front view and the side is the side view. This way you can mirror bones along the X-axis if you name them with ".L", "_L", ".left" or "_left", and ".R", etc, respectively.
- select the head's aramature (*szyja*), go to *Pose* mode, select all bones<sup>(well, it's only 1)</sup> with (<kbd>A</kbd>), and clear all transformations (menu: *Pose > Clear Transformation > All*)

If you go to front view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or menu: *View > Viewpoint > Front*) the dragon should now look at you

- remove all *Armature* () modifiers from every object. Apply the mirror modifiers if you want, do it top-down from the stack.
- join all *Armature* objects (grzywa...*, Oko, szczęka, dzialo szczekowe. kosci, szyja) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. The last one you select will be the remaining main armature. If a mesh moves then check the modifiers for an *Armature* modifier and remove it.
- apply Location, Scale, Rotation for the armature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, *All Transformations*)
- optional: this should be done for the mesh objects, too, but the *Mirror* modifier settings must be adjusted (mirror X-axis for the head, ...)
- optional: if you have applied the mirrors, rename all the bones on the dragon's left side (=right side from your point of view) to *Kosc- mocowanie mk1.L*. Then use the menu: *Armature > Symmetrize* in *Edit* mode to let create the bones on the right side.
- select all the mesh objects and the armature, then parent them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *With Empty Groups* in *Object mode*). *Empty Groups* will use the still existing weights. Adjust the modifier stack if you have *Mirror* modifiers.
- check the weight paint for the eyes and the jaw. There seem to be some "rogue" vertices that have a different weight.
- for better control make a bone hierarchy. Parent the bones (with offset). Something like *root -> neck -> head -> mane, jaw, eyes, "ears"*. This way everything will rotate with the head. This doesn't work with a flat hierarchy as shown in the screenshot.

[image: dragon with armature]